# How to enable Cassandra Password Authentication in Kubernetes deployment file

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I've been struggling with this for quite a while now. My effort so far is shown below. The env variable, `CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR`, in my opinion, is supposed to enable password authentication. However, I'm still able to logon without a password after redeploying with this config. Any ideas on how to enable password authentication in a Kubernetes deployment file?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cassandra
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: cassandra
            image: cassandra
            env:
              - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
                value: Cassandra
              - name: CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR
                value: PasswordAuthenticator
            ports:
              - containerPort: 7000
                name: intra-node
              - containerPort: 7001
                name: tls-intra-node
              - containerPort: 7199
                name: jmx
              - containerPort: 9042
                name: cql

            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
                name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

The environment is Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 2):

So I made few changes to the artifact you have mentioned:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cassandra
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: cassandra
            image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
            env:
              - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
                value: Cassandra
              - name: CASSANDRA_PASSWORD
                value: pass123
            ports:
              - containerPort: 7000
                name: intra-node
              - containerPort: 7001
                name: tls-intra-node
              - containerPort: 7199
                name: jmx
              - containerPort: 9042
                name: cql

            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
                name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

The changes I made were:

`image` name has been changed to `bitnami/cassandra:latest` and then replaced the `env` `CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR` with `CASSANDRA_PASSWORD`.

After you deploy the above artifact then I could authenticate as shown below

- Trying to exec into pod

  ```
  fedora@dhcp35-42:~/tmp/cassandra$ oc exec -it cassandra-2750650372-g8l9s bash
  root@cassandra-2750650372-g8l9s:/#
  ```
- Once inside the pod trying to authenticate with the server

  ```
  root@cassandra-2750650372-g8l9s:/# cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042 -p pass123 -u cassandra
  Connected to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9042.
  [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
  Use HELP for help.
  cassandra@cqlsh>
  ```

This image documentation can be found at https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra/

If you are not comfortable using the third party image and wanna use the image that upstream community manages then look for following solution, which is more DIY but also is more flexible.

---

To setup the password you were trying to use the `env` `CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR` but this is not merged proposal yet for the image `cassandra`. You can see the open PRs [here](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/pull/41#issuecomment-174004501).

Right now the upstream suggest doing the mount of file [`cassandra.yaml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cassandra/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml) at `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`, so that people can set whatever settings they want.

So follow the steps to do it:

- Download the [cassandra.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cassandra/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml)

I have made following changes to the file:

```
$ diff cassandra.yaml mycassandra.yaml 
103c103
< authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
---
> authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

- Create configmap with that file

We have to create [Kubernetes Configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/) which then we will mount inside the container, we cannot do host mount similar to docker.

```
    $ cp mycassandra.yaml cassandra.yaml
    $ k create configmap cassandraconfig --from-file ./cassandra.yaml
```

The name of configmap is `cassandraconfig`.

- Now edit the `deployment` to use this config and mount it in right place

  ```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: cassandra
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: cassandra
      spec:
        containers:
            - name: cassandra
              image: cassandra
              env:
                - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
                  value: Cassandra
              ports:
                - containerPort: 7000
                  name: intra-node
                - containerPort: 7001
                  name: tls-intra-node
                - containerPort: 7199
                  name: jmx
                - containerPort: 9042
                  name: cql

              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
                  name: data
                - mountPath: /etc/cassandra/
                  name: cassandraconfig
        volumes:
          - name: data
            emptyDir: {}
          - name: cassandraconfig
            configMap:
              name: cassandraconfig
  ```

Once you create this deployment.

- Now exec in the pod

  ```
  $ k exec -it cassandra-1663662957-6tcj6 bash
  root@cassandra-1663662957-6tcj6:/#
  ```
- Try using the client

  ```
  root@cassandra-1663662957-6tcj6:/# cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042
  Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires authentication.',)})
  ```

For more information on creating `configMap` and using it by mounting inside container you can read [this doc](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html), which helped me for this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for an elaborate response. From what I experienced using bitnami image, password auth is enabled by default. I'll give your suggestion a try, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to replace [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) *cassandra* Docker image with [bitnami](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra)'s version, but you still want to enable password authentication for accessing CQL shell, then you could achieve that by modification of Cassandra configuration file. Namely, enablement of password authentication is done by setting the following property definition in */etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml* file: `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`

As it is irrelevant whether certain property is defined once or multiple times, i.e. at the end the latest property definition will be used, aforementioned line can be simply appended to Cassandra configuration file. Alternative could be using *sed* for performing interactive search-and-replace, but IMHO that would be unnecessary overkill - both performance-wise and readability-wise.

Long-story short, specify container startup-command/entrypoint (with its arguments) so that first is config file properly adapted and then is executed image's original startup-command/entrypoint. Since in the container definition of Docker-Compose and Kubernetes y(a)ml it is only possible to define single startup-command, specify as a command standard/Bourne shell executing previous two steps.

Therefore the answer would be adding the following two lines:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "echo 'authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator' >> /etc/cassandra
/cassandra.yaml && docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f"]
```

so the OP's Kubernetes deployment file would be the following:

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: cassandra
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: cassandra
        spec:
          containers:
              - name: cassandra
                image: cassandra
                command: ["/bin/sh"]
                args: ["-c", "echo 'authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator' >> /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml && docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f"]
                env:
                  - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
                    value: Cassandra
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 7000
                    name: intra-node
                  - containerPort: 7001
                    name: tls-intra-node
                  - containerPort: 7199
                    name: jmx
                  - containerPort: 9042
                    name: cql
    
                volumeMounts:
                  - mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
                    name: data
          volumes:
            - name: data
              emptyDir: {}
```

Disclaimer: if 'latest' is used as the image tag of official Cassandra image, and if at some moment the original entrypoint (`docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f`) of image is changed, then this container might have issues starting Cassandra. However, since the entrypoint with its args is unchanged from the initial version until the latest version at the moment I was writing this post (4.0), it is very likely that it will remain as-is, so this approach/workaround should work fine.